# ExtJS 5 grid with grouping feature: Selected row with box shadow

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, extjs5

I'd like to add a box shadow to the selected row in a grid which also uses the grouping feature. Initially I just applied the box shadow to the `table` element of the selected row:

```
.x-grid-item-selected {
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px rgb(119, 119, 119) inset;
}
```

Unfortunately, the table element of the first row in a group also contains the group header which gave me this result when I selected the first row in a group:

[image]

Also I can't apply the box shadow to the `tr` element of the grid row (`.x-grid-item-selected .x-grid-row`) since chrome doesn't support box shadows on `tr` elements (at least not without setting their display property to block which would break the layout completely).

Applying the box shadow to each cell (`.x-grid-item-selected .x-grid-cell`) obviously doesn't give me the desired look neither:

[image]

Here's how I'd like the selected row to actually look like (just for the sake of completeness):

[image]

In ExtJS 4 I was able to accomplish this by using the RowWrap feature which was removed with ExtJS 5.

I'd really appreciate if someone could give me some help with this!

Here's a fiddle to play around with: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jkv

Thanks & best regards

*Ps.:* I've also asked this question on the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299150-Grid-with-grouping-feature-Selected-row-with-box-shadow)

Comment: Can you do the same thing via a background gradient? Chrome may support that on the TR element, giving you what you asked for.

Comment: @arthurakay Directly using the gradient on the `tr` element didn't work since chrome actually applies those gradients to all cells, but still I was able to find a solution by applying the gradient to every cell and using the `:first-child` & `:last-child` pseudo selectors. Thanks a lot for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found another solution which actually fits my needs even better since the usage of the `linear gradient` interfered with some other styles (e.g. background image of the first cell depending on content, ...).

This solution uses the pseudo element `after`:

```
.x-grid-item-selected .x-grid-row:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px rgb(119, 119, 119) inset;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jrm

The only downside of this method is that I have to set a fixed height.
Again, I'd really appreciate if someone comes up with an even better way to do this.

Thanks & best regards

Answer (score 1):

With the suggestion of [arthurakay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551436/arthurakay) who [commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093192/extjs-5-grid-with-grouping-feature-selected-row-with-box-shadow?noredirect=1#comment46428615_29093192) in mind I was able to find a suitable solution by using `linear-gradients` instead of `box shadows` which looks something like this:

```
.x-grid-item-selected .x-grid-cell {
    background:
        linear-gradient(top, rgb(119, 119, 119), transparent 6px),
        linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(119, 119, 119), transparent 6px);

    // Browser specific prefixed versions...
}

.x-grid-item-selected .x-grid-cell:first-child {
    background: 
        linear-gradient(top, rgb(119, 119, 119), transparent 6px),
        linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(119, 119, 119), transparent 6px),
        linear-gradient(left, rgb(119, 119, 119), transparent 6px);

    // Browser specific prefixed versions...
}

.x-grid-item-selected .x-grid-cell:last-child {
    background: 
        linear-gradient(top, rgb(119, 119, 119), transparent 6px),
        linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(119, 119, 119), transparent 6px),
        linear-gradient(right, rgb(119, 119, 119), transparent 6px);

    // Browser specific prefixed versions...
}
```

Since this is still somewhat cumbersome, I'd really appreciate any more input to solve this in a more "elegant" way.

Here's the working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jrh

Thanks & best regards